# Instagram location search for specific date/time period

Tags: search, location, instagram, geotagging

Using the Instagram API, would it be possible to write software that does a search of all public Instagram posts for a specific radius around a latitude/longitude location for a specific time/date period?

I understand that the API currently allows one to do a request for "recent" posts, but I am more interested in finding all historical posts between a given set of dates.

Many thanks.